# How do I get flyway.cmd to fail a build when no migration is necessary?

Tags: jenkins, flyway

I've built a pipeline in Jenkins that uses Flyway. I'd like to run a command that returns a positive exit code so that the build step fails if no database migration is necessary.

I could of course run flyway migrate and it would harmlessly do nothing, but I'd like to flag this to the end user as a problem if they're trying to deploy for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `validate` for this. If the exit code is `0` then no pending migrations have been found.